# MPI_Allreduce mix up sum processors

Tags: mpi

I have just parallelized a code but have some issues. I use mpi-allreduce. I have a one-dimensional interval binned in N subintervals. Each processor performs a sum of certain quantities for every bin. I use MP_allreduce to have the sum over each processor for every subinterval. The code seems to mix the subintervals so that in some subinterval processors contribute their value corresponding to a different subinterval. Is this a quite comon issue with mpi_Allreduce and how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: It is much more likely that you have written a program which does not do what you think it ought to than that there is some strange misbehaviour of `mpi_allreduce` occurring.  Seriously, how do you expect anyone to provide useful help without showing your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code, it is very difficult to explain what exactly is your error. However from my understanding of your question, you're dividing an array of elements into intervals and then assigning an interval to each process. Each process then computes its partial sum. Now to sum up all the elements, you're using the `MPI_Allreduce()` function. So here's a simple implementation of the above scenario.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

int *create_rand_nums(int num_elements) {
    int *rand_nums = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * num_elements);
    assert(rand_nums != NULL);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
        rand_nums[i] = rand()%100;
    }
    return rand_nums;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s num_elements_per_proc\n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    int num_elements_per_proc = atoi(argv[1]);

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    int *rand_nums, *local_nums;  

    if(world_rank == 0)
    { 
        srand(time(NULL)*world_rank);
        rand_nums = create_rand_nums(world_size*num_elements_per_proc);
    }

    local_nums = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*num_elements_per_proc);
    MPI_Scatter(rand_nums,num_elements_per_proc,MPI_INT,local_nums,num_elements_per_proc,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
    int local_sum = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_elements_per_proc; i++) 
    {
        local_sum += local_nums[i];
    }

    int global_sum;
    MPI_Allreduce(&local_sum, &global_sum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("World Rank: %d \t Global Sum: %d \n",world_rank,global_sum);
    if(world_rank == 0)
        free(rand_nums);
    free(local_nums);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Here's what happens in the program

- The root (`world_rank` 0) generates the random numbers of the size determined by the argument to the program.
- The root assigns the sub-intervals to all processes (including itself) using `MPI_Scatter()`.
- Each process computes its local sum.
- The global sum is computed by the `MPI_Allreduce()` call.